# wondered what is meaning of specific script code

Tags: javascript

I wondered meaning of specific script code
so I posted this question 3month ago and now i get baned ;;
of course not only this question ther is one more...
anyway I realized why this question get colsed as a bad question.

1.var slideIndex = 1; // why is it set 1? what is mean?

2.function plusSlides(n) { // what is meaning of (n)?

3.var i; // what is mean and what is it for?

that time I didn't serched well before I upload this question
and asked so basic qusetion which highly i can find proper information if i search;;

the point of this post is..
can you help me to get out of this ban?

this post is meaning less post.... but deleting colsed question is not helping to get out of ban so... here i am;

Comment: There are tutorials and books that cover basic JavaScript concepts (including variables, scoping, and parameters). Reading these resources will likely be productive use of time. Many of these resources are provided in the javascript tag info..

Comment: As for why the variable `slideIndex` is initially set to 1: what else would make a good default value? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates a slide of pictures (like a carousel) which allows the user to click from a picture to the next.

1. `var slideIndex = 1` creates a global variable and sets its initial value to 1. This is the variable that determines which slide image will display. By setting it to 1, the first picture to show on the slide will be the first in the list.
2. `function plusSlides(n) ...` is the function that adds (or subtracts) the desired number to the global variable: `slideIndex`. It accepts a parameter: `n` which it adds to that `slideIndex`. If n is negative, it will subtract it from `slideIndex`
3. `var i;` This is a global "counter" variable used to iterate through the slides and the dots in the the `for` loops below.

These are really basic Javascript concepts that you can find in any tutorial. You should look into those

Answer (score 2):

1.var slideIndex = 1; // why is it set 1? what is mean?

It will starts from 1. If you set to 0 it will starts from total no of slides also

```
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
```

2.function plusSlides(n) { // what is meaning of (n)?

Here n is defined to index of slide. When you clicked right arrow then it will go for next slide. and vice versa.

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

3.var i; // what is mean and what is it for?

its initialization for loop variable

```
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
```